# Win PowerShell + Laravel, corrupt system?

Tags: php, windows, laravel, powershell, laravel-artisan

Hello to these programming on **Laravel** on Windows Environment.

I don't think this will have an easy solution, I will drop it here though.

I am programming using Windows **PowerShell** as my default terminal. And all of a sudden, working on a *Laravel PHP Project*, seems that the commands "`php artisan`" are not working fine.

There's how it looks the command "`php artistan list`" in my blue **PowerShell**, and in the normal black Windows CMD:

**CMD and powershell:**

[image]

Using the normal CMD seems to work fine, meanwhile in **PowerShell**, results do not work fine.

I've reinstalled `Composer`, tried in **Laravel 5.2 & 5.3** versions, and using **XAMPP PHP 5.6.15**.

Files weren't from Git, were created there.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't like the color encoding. I don't have any suggestions, but maybe that information can help you.

Comment: Please check your _environment variables_ are in place.

Comment: As long as it's only about the color encoding, worries me less.

Environment variables are set properly. I haven't changed any Path or File.

Thanks for your quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't support UNIX ANSI escape sequences (ANSI Color Codes).

Use Windows Command Prompt (CMD.EXE).

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've tried from another User's account inside my same Windows OS, and it appears to be working fine, the ANSI color codes set, as it have been working before.

[new capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKdRu.png)

Therefore there must be something wrong. Will check my PATH file or reset all plugins and files of programming environment.

Thanks a lot for your help!